# Issue with Exchange 2010 and Removing a Mailbox Database

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-migration

I did a 2003 to 2010 transition and everything is working well. During the 2010 install, a database was copied over with a random number at the end. I found out and moved three system mailboxes out of it into the database that all of the client accounts are in. I used the EMS to move those mailboxes to the other store then used the EMC to remove the mailbox database.

Problem is, I am getting an error every few hours in event viewer now complaining about this database. Error is:

MSExchageRepl - 4098
The Microsoft Exchange Replication service couldn't find a valid configuration for database '5f012f40-3bad-4003-a373-dbc0ffb6736f' on server 'SERVER'. Error: (nothing reported after this)

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? In advance, I appreciate your help and thx for your valuable input!

Comment: Have you restarted any of the Exchange services (or rebooted) since removing the database?  I don't know that it's needed, I'm just curious.

Comment: Hey William. Thx for the comment. I actually have rebooted several times. You could say I am in Event View cleaning mode attacking ever error/warning the system has spit out. I believe Exchange thinks that the database exists and is trying to load it. Just not sure why since Get-MailboxDatabase and Get-PublicFoldersDatabase do not report the GUID being valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I have no answer for this. It appears to have worked itself out over time and no longer complains about the issue.

However, if someone finds a solution, I would be interested to know.